# Access Report conditional format if value is in SQL result

Tags: vba, ms-access, reporting

I'm looking to do some conditional formatting, and I have a long list of starting and ending ranges.  I also have a query that finds possibly problematic ranges.  I want the values that are in the problematic query result to be highlighted (bold, red etc).  How can I acheive this?

Example:

Report shows:
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10

Another query shows 3, 8

So in the report I would want 3 and 8 to be highlighted because they exist in the other query.

Comment: You could just make the background color of the textbox control that the fields are bound to the color and style of your choosing.

Comment: @Invent-Animate - I don't understand... its not ALL the data in those fields that should be highlighted, just some of them.

Comment: How many queries are there? From your question it seems like the problematic query is a separate entity, but perhaps uses the same data. Maybe throw some sample data/results?